JAR file cannot find main class
I'm trying to build my project into an executable JAR file. Since I was having problems I reduced the structure to a very simple one.
I have this simple file structure:
src\
src\test.java
src\test.class
MANIFEST.mf

Here is test.java:
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, World!");
    }
}

and here is MANIFEST.mf:
Main-Class: test

Yes, I put a new line at the end of the manifest.
So far I tried to compile the project using these commands:
jar cfm test.jar .\MANIFEST.mf .\src\test.class

But the resulting file gives an error when I run java -jar test.jar:
Error: Could not find or load main class test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test

What causes this? How do I fix it? I tried looking up other questions but they all either forgot to add the end of line in the manifest or didn't include their classes correctly.
Any suggestion helps!

You don't need to mess with manifests any more: jar cvfe test.jar test test.class then java -jar test.jar Class names begin upper case

check the content of the JAR file - jar tvf test.jar or any ZIP app (WinZIP, 7-zip, ...) -- probably the .class is being added as src\test.class (but it is not in the src package) -- try jar cfm test.jar MANIFEST.mf -C src test.class

If you want to run the command from the directory you're in, then jar cvfe test.jar test -C src test.class but of course your classes shouldn't be in a directory called 'src' ;)
